# Não consigo pegar dados da API com Axios no React

Tags: javascript, react, axios

Ao tentar pegar dados de uma API com axios , consigo vê-los no console ao utilizar o console.log. Entretanto, ao tentar colocar o resultado dentro de uma variável no React com useState, a variável não recebe esses dados.

```
const [versiculos, setVersiculos] = useState([])

useEffect( () => {

  axios.get("https://www.abibliadigital.com.br/api/verses/nvi/random",{
    headers: header
  }).then(response => setVersiculos(response.data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))

 console.log(versiculos)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Antes de tudo, visualizei o retorno da API que você esta trabalhando e percebi que ela retorna um objeto, portanto ao invés de definir meu estado inicial como um array vazio, preferi passar já no padrão que ele irá retornar:

```
const [verse, setVerse] = useState({book: {}, chapter: '', verse: '', text: ''});
```

E em seguida desestruturei o estado, por pura preferência na hora de renderizar  as informações:

```
const { text, book, chapter, number } = verse;
```

Não sei se você configurou seu axios, e também não sei se a forma que configuro é a mais viável, de toda forma, consegui um resultado positivo com o seguinte código:

```
const handleAPI = axios.create({
baseURL: 'https://www.abibliadigital.com.br/api/verses/nvi/random',
})
```

Em seguida, criei a função que vai realizar a requisição a api:

```
const getVerse = async () => {
const response = await handleAPI.get();
setVerse(response.data);
}
```

Passo essa função no useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  getVerse();
}, []);
```

Para visualizar o retorno da requisição, efetuei as seguintes alterações:

```
return (
  <div>
    {verse && (
      <div>
        <h1>{text} </h1>
        <h2>{book.name}, {chapter}:{number}</h2>
      </div> )}
    <button onClick={getVerse}>Get Verses</button>
  </div>
 );
```

Caso prefira, disponibilizei nesse [link do CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/intelligent-worker-rmg1fd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Espero que tenha ajudado :)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Notei que o problema era com a condição de renderização. Aliás, ver seu código me ajudou bastante.Toda vez que fazia a requisição , o console apontava que não podia ler o objeto porque não continha nada.Utilizei o && para ver se tinha algo no estado antes de renderizar e começou a funcionar normalmente.

Answer (score -2):

Ja tentou usar null, invés de [] no valor do versiculos.
Alem disso, geralmente a response vem em Json, tenta dar um console.log(response) pra ver o formato e se tiver em Json converter.